# Windows 7 long delay before opening videos

Tags: windows-7, windows

Recently I've been having a to wait for about 30 seconds before a video file opens either with Windows Media Player, VLC Player, or Media Player Classic.

Each time I try to open a video the progress bar starts and it stays there for almost a 40 seconds (screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPkQl.jpg) until it stops then the video file opens.

It happens with all formats I have: mp4, avi, flv, mpeg.

I have Ad-Aware Antivirus running and it detected no problems on my machine. I would like to solve this without having to reinstall Windows.

PD: I have a very fast machine and the videos are on a new Samsung SSD, so I don't think that's the root of the problem

Comment: My first thought is if the SSD is using the current firmware revision. The second is you will need to benchmark the file access to verify if this is a codec problem or a file read access problem. These are non-network files? The fact this happens on several different programs and video container formats indicates a file access problem honestly.

Comment: The video files aren't on a network location, they're on my PC and my SSD has the latest firmware.

Comment: Time to run a benchmark on your SSD to confirm its working to its specifications.

Comment: It is, even  better than with factory defaults. Only video files seem to be affected

Comment: My only suggestion would be to use a Live Linux disk, use VLC, and see if the problem exists.  This will now confirm if its a codec problem.

Comment: What happens when disable "real-time" virus protection and/or add an exception (whitelist) for the specific folder that the video is in?

Comment: @horatio, yeah it seems that was causing the delay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you confirmed: the virus protection must scan the file. If this is a feature-length video, then it is probably in the GB size range and the file takes a noticeable amount of time to be scanned, or you can attempt to whitelist a folder into which you place pre-scanned files to avoid the scanning delay.

Comment: I don't think my current antivirus has that option. I can only disable real-time protection.

Comment: Ad aware? Check under "scans" settings for an exclusion list. AFAIK, this list is honored for real-time scanning as well as scheduled scans.